# coalesce in IQ is not working

Tags: sap-iq

I am using something like this:

```
select @x=coalesce(@x,'')+col1 from testdatatable
```

This works perfectly on SQL Server 2008 but for IQ it fails:

> SELECT returns more than one row

Answer (score 0):

We need more information on what your goal is here.

Is your select statement returning multiple rows? If so, IQ is attempting to set a single (varchar?) variable, @x, with many values...which isn't possible.  It doesn't look like coalesce is your problem to me.

If are you trying get a single row back from testdatatable, and concatenate that single row's col1 with the @x, why not

```
select
  @x = isnull(@x, '') + col1
from testdatatable
where (clause to get single row)
```

Comment: I am trying to get multiple rows concatenated.

Comment: Also I dont have IQ 15 where a function called List works for this

Comment: are you okay with repeats, or do you want distinct values of col1? How many rows are we talking about here?